# Node Modules - exporting a variable versus exporting functions that reference it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Easiest to explain with code:

```
##### module.js
var count, incCount, setCount, showCount;
count = 0; 

showCount = function() {
 return console.log(count);
};
incCount = function() {
  return count++;
};
setCount = function(c) {
  return count = c;
 };

exports.showCount = showCount;
exports.incCount = incCount;
exports.setCount = setCount; 
exports.count = count; // let's also export the count variable itself

#### test.js
var m;
m = require("./module.js");
m.setCount(10);
m.showCount(); // outputs 10
m.incCount();  
m.showCount(); // outputs 11
console.log(m.count); // outputs 0
```

The exported functions work as expected. But I'm not clear why m.count isn't also 11.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`exports.count = count`

Your setting a property `count` on an object `exports` to be the value of `count`. I.e. 0.

Everything is pass by value not pass by reference.

If you were to define `count` as a getter like such :

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "count", {
  get: function() { return count; }
});
```

Then `exports.count` would always return the current value of `count` and thus be 11

Comment: Not everything is pass by value! Functions and objects are always passed by reference.

Comment: @zetlen no they are passed by value. The value they are passing is a reference to an object. Pass by reference is pointers. We have no pointers

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong, but numbers are immutable types. When you change the value of `count` then your reference changes too. So `exports.count` references to the old `count` value.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, functions and objects (including arrays) are assigned to variables by reference, and strings and numbers are assigned by value--that is, by making a copy. If `var a = 1` and `var b = a` and `b++`, `a` will still equal 1.

On this line:

```
exports.count = count; // let's also export the count variable itself
```

you made a by-value copy of the count variable. The setCount(), incCount() and showCount() operations all operate on the count variable inside the closure, so m.count doesn't get touched again. If those variables were operating on this.count, then you'd get the behavior you expect--but you probably don't want to export the count variable anyway.

Comment: "by reference" implies pointers. Where are these pointers we have in javascript?

Comment: Fair enough. What would you use to describe the difference between object assignment/function assignment and string assignment? No, it's not a literal memory location, but two references to an object will modify or display the same object, and that's not true of a string. What do you call that?

Comment: @zetlen, this article succinctly answers your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:JavaScript/Guide/Obsolete_Pages/Defining_Functions. In essence, all JavaScript functions pass-by-value. The interesting question is: what value do they pass? For primitive types, it's the datum itself and for non-primitive types, it's the local of the entity.

Comment: Thanks, @Thierry! In the years since I answered this question I've come to understand what actual by-reference would look like. Reassigning to the local name for your object does not modify the value of that name outside the body of your function, which is what happens in actual pass-by-reference languages--you're receiving a reference and you're allowed to modify it. Thanks for the link!