# Sharing the variable among multiple files in node js

Tags: javascript

in index.js

`let a=[];`

```
const ab = function(){
a.push(1);
 console.log("b",a);}
module.exports = {
a:a,
ab:ab
};
```

#

in main.js

```
var lo = require("./a")
console.log(lo.a);
lo.ab();
console.log(lo.a);
```

When I run main.js the first console.log in empty Array but second console.log is [1]. My question is when we importing, it is referred to a in index.js or will it give a copy of a in index.js

If I slightly change the index.js to

```
let a=[];

const ab = function(){
a=[];
a.push(1);
console.log("b",a);}
module.exports = {
a:a,
ab:ab
};
```

then the output is [] and [].

Why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

"a" would be exposed to your consumer module via reference. Check out https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching for details.

Comment: Module caching has nothing to with the pass by reference in a module closure

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When you import, 'a' is referred to 'a' in index.js. In javascript, variables are always passed by reference, except for primitives. In this case, a is an array. So, the same object will be referred.

Comment: JavaScript does not have pass by reference, arrays and objects are pass by 'copy of reference' and primitives are pass by value

Comment: My mistake. I was trying to mean the same.

Comment: If So, When I change my index.js to below 


favorite
in index.js

let a=[];

const ab = function(){
a=[];
a.push(1);
 console.log("b",a);}
module.exports = {
a:a,
ab:ab
};

then output is [],[]

Comment: This answer might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381802/node-modules-exporting-a-variable-versus-exporting-functions-that-reference-it

Comment: If it referred to a in index.js, then in the second case also it should print [] and [1] but getting [],[].