# How to reset global variable on custom hook

Tags: jestjs, rect

I need to reset global variable on custom hook when unit testing React component. I have read few tutorials and StackOverflow answers to this simple task, but without luck to implement it correctly.

**The problem**

userInfo is undefined in the first and second test but when runs the third test userInfo is defined then on useEffect doesn't change the value... So my question is how to reset userInfo for each test.

```
jest.resetModules // doesn't work
jest.isolateModules // doesn't work
```

My simplest possible setup for single test is as following:

**My Environment**

```
"jest": "^24.9.0",
```

**My Hook**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

// This variable is an object save user info
let userInfo = null;

export default (authService) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo !== null || authService === null) {
      return;
    }

    setLoading(true);
    authService
      ?.getUser()
      .then((response) => {
        userInfo = {owners: [{...response, cost_center: response.costCenter || "N/A"}]};
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setError({
          title: "authService Error",
          message: "Error getting user",
          status: 500
        });
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [authService]);

  return [userInfo, error, loading];
};
```

**My Test**

```
import {renderHook} from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import * as sinon from "sinon";
import {getSpyOfUseOktaAuth} from "../../../__tests__/";
import {Info, InfoFromRequest, InfoWithNoCostCenter} from "../../../__tests__/";

describe("useGetUserInfo", () => {
  let clock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    clock.restore();
  });

  it("should set the error value after the getUserInfo function throws an error", async () => {
    const useGetUserInfo = require("../index").default;

    const errorMessage = {
      title: "authService Error",
      message: "Error getting user from",
      status: 500
    };

    const getAuthMock = getSpyOfUseAuth({
      Auth: {
        signOut: jest.fn(),
        getUser: jest.fn(async () => {
          throw new Error("Auth Error");
        })
      },
      authState: {}
    });

    const {result, rerender, waitForNextUpdate} = renderHook(() =>
      useGetUserInfo(getAuthMock.results.Auth)
    );

    rerender();

    await waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(result.current[1]).toEqual(errorMessage);
    getAuthMock.instance.mockRestore();
  });

  it("should return the user info from after run the getUserInfo function", async () => {
    const useGetUserInfo = require("../index").default;

    let authService = null;

    const {result, rerender, waitForNextUpdate} = renderHook(() => useGetOktaUserInfo(authService));

    const getAuthMock = getSpyOfUseAuth({
      Auth: {
        signOut: jest.fn(),
        getUser: jest.fn(async () => Info)
      },
      authState: {}
    });

    authService = getAuthMock.results.Auth;

    rerender();

    await waitForNextUpdate();

    expect(result.current[0]).toEqual(InfoFromRequest);
    getAuthMock.instance.mockRestore();
  });

  it("should set cost_center as in data as N/A if costCenter is not defined in user info ", async () => {
    const useGetUserInfo = require("../index").default;

    const getAuthMock = getSpyOfUseAuth({
      Auth: {
        signOut: jest.fn(),
        getUser: jest.fn(async () => InfoWithNoCostCenter)
      },
      authState: {}
    });

    const {result, rerender} = renderHook(() => useGetUserInfo(getAuthMock.results.Auth));

    rerender();

    expect(result.current[0].owners[0].cost_center).toEqual("N/A");
    getAuthMock.instance.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that either you export the 'userInfo' variable from the hook and you set it to null manually before each test, or you treat 'userInfo' as a state variable just like 'error' and 'loading'

If you go for the first option, you will need to export by reference [Node Modules - exporting a variable versus exporting functions that reference it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381802/node-modules-exporting-a-variable-versus-exporting-functions-that-reference-it)

For the second option, it would be something like this

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";


export default (authService) => {
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
 if (userInfo !== null || authService === null) {
  return;
 }

setLoading(true);
authService
  ?.getUser()
  .then((response) => {
    setUserInfo({owners: [{...response, cost_center: response.costCenter || "N/A"}]});
  })
  .catch(() => {
    setError({
      title: "authService Error",
      message: "Error getting user",
      status: 500
    });
  })
  .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [authService]);

  return [userInfo, error, loading];
};
```

Comment: I would like to use an state but when the hook will be instantiated for other component the state will be reseted for that reason I have userInfo outside of hook...

by the way if I can't find the solution I will export the variable

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The solution I got is to separate each case into different files. As jest load each file in a different process, this will be enough